# SQL - How to select TOP 5 from inner statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following query working properly.

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM (
         SELECT * 
         FROM table 
         WHERE name IS NULL 
         ORDER BY date DESC 
         LIMIT 20
         ) AS T 
    ORDER BY date ASC;
```

What I would like is to select the top 5 records of that sql select query. So according to the posts I read I should only have to add TOP 5. See here below:

```
 SELECT TOP 5 * 
        FROM (
             SELECT * 
             FROM table 
             WHERE name IS NULL 
             ORDER BY date DESC 
             LIMIT 20
             ) AS T 
        ORDER BY date ASC;
```

Unfortunately mysql is telling me that there is a syntax error but I don't get it. Thank you in advance for replies. Cheers. Marc

Comment: for MySQL the standard is LIMIT I've never seen TOP in MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add another limit..

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM (
         SELECT * 
         FROM table 
         WHERE name IS NULL 
         ORDER BY date DESC 
         LIMIT 20
         ) AS T 
    ORDER BY date ASC
    LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: This is doing exactly what I was looking for actually. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

The TOP clause is not supported by all database

as it's just for limit the number of result, you can use the LIMIT

```
    SELECT  * 
    FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM table 
        WHERE name IS NULL 
        ORDER BY date DESC 
        LIMIT 20
    ) AS T 
    ORDER BY date ASC
    LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: This is doing exactly what I was looking for actually. Thank you very much :)